# treatment of null value on a dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set where null value is

```
df.isnull().sum()
country                       0
country_long                  0
name                          0
gppd_idnr                     0
capacity_mw                   0
latitude                     46
longitude                    46
primary_fuel                  0
other_fuel1                   0
other_fuel2                   0
other_fuel3                 908
commissioning_year          380
owner                         0
source                        0
url                           0
geolocation_source            0
wepp_id                     908
year_of_capacity_data       388
generation_gwh_2013         524
generation_gwh_2014         507
generation_gwh_2015         483
generation_gwh_2016         471
generation_gwh_2017         465
generation_data_source        0
estimated_generation_gwh    908
```

I tried mean mode max min and std all the methods but all null values is not removing
when I try

```
df['wepp_id']=df['wepp_id'].replace(np.NAN,df['wepp_id'].mean())
```

its not working same things happen on median , std and min, max also

Comment: Please show a sample from your dataset, especially the column 'wepp_id'.

Comment: 0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
       ..
903   NaN
904   NaN
905   NaN
906   NaN
907   NaN
Name: wepp_id, Length: 908, dtype: float64

Comment: @YasharAhmadov i just gave wepp_id row

Comment: Okay, thanks, but better to add screenshot to the question. Does df['wepp_id']=df['wepp_id'].fillna(5) work for example?

Comment: yes its coming now wepp_id as 5 , but is it a  correct way ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `df['wepp_id']=df['wepp_id'].fillna(df['wepp_id'].mean())`

If this does not work, then it means that your column is not of number type. If it is an string type, then you need to do this first:

`df['wepp_id'] = df['wepp_id'].astype(float)`

Then run the command in the first line.

Comment: hi , df['wepp_id']=df['wepp_id'].fillna(df['wepp_id'].mean()) this is i larady tried, its not working . df['wepp_id']=df['wepp_id'].fillna(0) for this code the null value is coming 0

Comment: but i am not sure this is correct

Comment: Can you please print out df.dtypes? It might be that your column is not a number.

Comment: i know that i alrady changes to integer by using lencode methode

Comment: Please see the updated answer. If it is a string, then you need to first change it to float.